# Wastebin full error in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu

I'm trying to delete files from a USB flash drive and I get the following message:

> The wastebin has reached its maximum size!
>   Empty the wastebin manually.

There are no files in the wastebin and the `Empty` button is greyed out.

How can I solve this? Also is there a way to change the amount of data that the wastebin can hold?

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove `.Trash*` (where `*` stands for some other chars) on a usb stick:

```
rm -rf /media/$USER/<USB mount name here>/.Trash*
```

(if You have an older kubuntu, say 12.04, the path to USB stick won't contain `$USER`).

If it wouldn't help try to remove `Trash` folder at home:

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash
```

Comment: I believe the issue was files on the USB drive, in which case I think this might work: Open the USB in Dolphin. Find the option to show hidden files. Open .local/share/Trash. Delete these files by selecting them and then pressing Shift + Delete on the keyboard. KDE has a separate Trash for each drive, which can cause confusion on movable drives.

Comment: because if I am right you can fix your answer now.

Comment: @JosefOttosson just did it. Please review.